# How to select a specific element when returned multiple elements in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

So I am trying to select an element using their placeholder like this:

```
fireEvent.focus(screen.getByPlaceholderText('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

And this is giving me an error saying it found multiple elements with the said placeholder. Here are the matching elements.:

```
<input
      class="StyledInput"
      hasvalue=""
      label="Date of birth"
      placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
      tabindex="0"
      value=""
      variant=""
    />

    <input
      class="StyledInput"
      hasvalue=""
      label="Expiry date"
      placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
      tabindex="0"
      value=""
      variant=""
    />
```

It's returning me two elements but I only want to select the first one. How can I get that specific element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `getAllByPlaceholderText` method, otherwise, you will get an error:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the placeholder text of: DD/MM/YYYY

The return value of `const inputs = screen.getAllByPlaceholderText('DD/MM/YYYY')` is an element list, you can get the first input element by array index - `inputs[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.